# Libgdx Android dual touchpad issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I currently got a problem when using two touchpads, when using 'popup' mode it every now and then happens that the wrong touchpad is being registered as touched. Meaning when I am using the left touchpad it sometimes picks it up as touching the right one, so the knob of the right touchpad gets moved to the far left of the touchpad area. It happens mostly when two fingers touch the screen "almost" simultaneously.
I am guessing there might be an error in my code, but I don't see it.
Furthmore this problem only seems to occur when one or both touchpads are in POPUP/INVISIBLE mode, so that is most likely where the problem lies.

This is from the update method of my program:

```
// MOVEMENT TOUCHPAD
switch(movementMode) {
case STATIC:
    if(movementTouchpad.getKnobPercentX() != 0 || movementTouchpad.getKnobPercentY() != 0)
        moveCamera();
    break;
case POPUP:
case INVISIBLE:
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched() && !movementTouchpad.isTouched()) {
        // To prevent unwanted relocation of the touchpad
        screenPosition.set(-1, -1);

        // Store the position if the left half is touched
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
                if(Gdx.input.getX(i) < (screenWidth / 2.0f)) {
                    screenPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i));
                    break;
                }                               
            }
        }

        // See if the touchpad needs to be repositioned
        if((screenPosition.x != -1) &&
        (screenPosition.x > (touchpadWidth / 2)) && 
        (screenPosition.x < ((screenWidth / 2) - (touchpadWidth / 2))) &&
        (screenPosition.y > (touchpadHeight / 2)) && 
        (screenPosition.y < (screenHeight - (touchpadHeight / 2)))) {
            // Reposition the movement touchpad
            movementTouchpad.setX(screenPosition.x - (touchpadWidth / 2));
            movementTouchpad.setY((screenHeight - screenPosition.y) - (touchpadHeight / 2));
            // Fire a fake touch event
            stagePosition = movementStage.screenToStageCoordinates(screenPosition);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageX(stagePosition.x);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageY(stagePosition.y);
            movementTouchpad.fire(fakeTouchDownEvent);
        }
        // Give feedback when touched too close to the border
        else if(screenPosition.x != -1) {
            switch(feedbackMode) {
            case NONE:
                break;
            case SOUND:
                //TODO
                break;
            case TACTILE:
                Gdx.input.vibrate(VIBRATION_DURATION);
                break;
            case VISUAL:
                //TODO
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(movementTouchpad.getKnobPercentX() != 0 || movementTouchpad.getKnobPercentY() != 0)
        moveCamera();
    break;
}

// ROTATION TOUCHPAD
switch(rotationMode) { 
case STATIC:
    if(rotationTouchpad.getKnobPercentX() != 0 || rotationTouchpad.getKnobPercentY() != 0)
        rotateCamera();
    break;
case POPUP:
case INVISIBLE:
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched() && !rotationTouchpad.isTouched()) {
        // To prevent unwanted relocation of the touchpad
        screenPosition.set(-1, -1);

        // Store the position if the right half is touched
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
                if(Gdx.input.getX(i) > (screenWidth / 2.0f)) {
                    screenPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i));
                    break;
                }                               
            }
        }

        // See if the touchpad needs to be repositioned
        if((screenPosition.x != -1) &&
        (screenPosition.x > ((touchpadWidth / 2) + (screenWidth / 2))) && 
        (screenPosition.x < (screenWidth - (touchpadWidth / 2))) &&
        (screenPosition.y > (touchpadHeight / 2)) && 
        (screenPosition.y < (screenHeight - (touchpadHeight / 2)))) {
            // Reposition the rotation touchpad
            rotationTouchpad.setX(screenPosition.x - (touchpadWidth / 2));
            rotationTouchpad.setY((screenHeight - screenPosition.y) - (touchpadHeight / 2));
            // Fire a fake touch event
            stagePosition = movementStage.screenToStageCoordinates(screenPosition);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageX(stagePosition.x);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageY(stagePosition.y);
            rotationTouchpad.fire(fakeTouchDownEvent);                      
        }
        // Give feedback when touched too close to the border
        else if(screenPosition.x != -1) {
            switch(feedbackMode) {
            case NONE:
                break;
            case SOUND:
                //TODO
                break;
            case TACTILE:
                Gdx.input.vibrate(VIBRATION_DURATION);
                break;
            case VISUAL:
                //TODO
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(rotationTouchpad.getKnobPercentX() != 0 || rotationTouchpad.getKnobPercentY() != 0)
        rotateCamera();
    break;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what type of phone are you using?

Comment: I got a LG Optimus 4X HD (P880). To my knowledge multitouch functionality works fine on it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be beacuse your phone might be be fully multi-touch support it might only have touch to zoom, this happened to me before with a HTC desire, have a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MLUmJL_Px0) and see if this is the same issue. Get a touch screen app and see if you are having the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I got a LG Optimus 4X HD (P880). I doubt that my phone is the problem, but I will look into it.